# Access specific parameter of a function

Tags: php, function

How could I access specific parameter from a function, example:

```
function someFunction()
{    echo $a = 7;
     echo $b = 70;
}
someFunction();//770
```

How can I return only `$a` or `$b`, is possible ?

Comment: other than modifying the function?  Nothing really.  If a `class` on the other hand you can make variables public in a class

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to return only one parameter then you just use the return statement.

```
<?php
function someFunction()
{   
    $a = 7;
    $b = 70;
   return [$a, $b];
}
$arrayS = someFunction();//array containing $a and $b
echo $arrayS[0]."\n";
echo $arrayS[1]."\n";  
echo "\n";
echo "Another way to access variables\n";
echo someFunction()[0]."\n";
echo someFunction()[1]."\n";
```

Comment: You can use a conditional statement.  I've updated my answer with a new example at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

### `echo` vs `return`

First of all, I think it is important to note that `echo` and `return` have very different behaviors and are used in very different contexts. [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) simply outputs whatever is passed to it, either to an html page, or to the server log.

```
<?php
    $a = 5;

    function printFoo() {
        echo 'foo';
    }

    echo '<h1>Hello World!</h1>';  // prints an h1 tag to the page
    echo $a;  // prints 5 to the page
    foo();  // prints foo to the page
?>
```

[`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) on the other hand is used to "[end] execution of the current function, and return its argument as the value of the function call." `return` can only ever take one argument. It can also only be *executed* once in a function; once it is reached, the code will jump out of the function back to where the function was invoked.

```
<?php

    function getFoo() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    // print the value returned by getFoo() directly
    echo getFoo();

    // store it in a variable to be used elsewhere
    $foo = getFoo(); // $foo is now equal to the string 'foo'

    function getFooBar() {
        return 'foobar'; // code beyond this statement will not be executed

        echo 'something something';
        return 'another foobar';
    }

    echo getFooBar(); // prints 'foobar'

?>
```

### function paramters

As it stands, `someFunction` can only return `$a` or `$b` or an array containing `$a` and `$b`, which may become a problem if, say, you need to print out `$c`. To make the function more reusable, you can pass it an [argument](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) and then reuse the function wherever you like.

```
<?php

    function printSomething($myVar) {
        echo $myVar;
    }

    $a = 7;
    $b = 70;
    $c = 770;

    printSomething($a) . '\n';
    printSomething($b) . '\n';
    printSomething($c) . '\n';
    printSomething(7000); // you don't have to pass it a variable!

    // Output:
    // 7
    // 70
    // 700
    // 7000

?>
```

Comment: Tks for atention, good explanation, but last example `$a, $b, $c` become a global variable right? I dont know if it's a risk or benefit, but im prefer last example acept answer, also idk if is correct, but work in jail exacly how i plan....

Comment: @MagicHat they are global in the sense that they don't belong to a specific function or object, yes. Keep in mind, this is intended to be a quick demonstration, not a perfect implementation to be copy/pasted directly in your code.